# The parameter on my post action for WebAPI is always null

Tags: .net, json, f#, asp.net-web-api

I have an F# WebAPI project and the parameter for the Post method is always set to null for some reason.

(the names are all anonymized)

Here is the controller:

```
type TestController() =
    inherit ApiController()
    member x.Get () =
        getValues ()

    member x.Post ([<FromBody>] values: Values) =
        storeValues values
```

This is how the record `Values` is defined as:

```
type TypeA = {
    Id: string
    ....
    }

....

type Values = {
    AValues: list<TypeA>
    BValues: list<TypeB>
    CValues: list<TypeC>
    }
```

And in my view I make a POST call to the API like so:

```
        return $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: JSON.stringify(params),
            contentType: "application/json",
            beforeSend: function (jqXHR) { jqXHR.setRequestHeader("X-HTTP-Method", type); }
        });
```

where `data` comes out to:

```
{
    "AValues":[{"Id":"blahblah", ....}],
    "BValues":[...],
    "CValues":[...]
}
```

I updated the JS to make `data` evaluate to:

```
{
    "Values":
    {
        "AValues":[{"Id":"blahblah", ....}],
        "BValues":[...],
        "CValues":[...]
    }
}
```

and now the debugger throws a nullreference exception and says that Requests is null (breakpoint is on my record definition).

The problem is that it does hit the Post method in the controller, but the `values` is always set to null.

Comment: what does `JSON.stringify(params)` produce? I mean what is your JSON data you are sending?

Comment: It's listed above. `{
    "AValues":[{"Id":"blahblah", ....}],
    "BValues":[...],
    "CValues":[...]
}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I forwarded the issue to [Ryan Riley](http://wizardsofsmart.net/) who is expect on both F# and Web API and he said the following:

> You can't use records with the default model binder, even if you made
>   the members mutable, because records don't have default constructors.
>   F# 3.0 introduces a CLIMutableAttribute [1] that will allow records to be
>   used this way.
>
> [1] http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fsharpteam/archive/2012/07/19/more-about-fsharp-3.0-language-features.aspx